# How to access value of first index of array in Go templates

Tags: go, struct, slice, go-templates

So I have and html template when using this I get the object:

```
<div>Foobar {{ index .Doc.Users 0}}</div>
```

Output:

```
<div>Foobar {MyName my@email.com}</div>
```

I just want to use the `Name` field I have tried many iterations without success:

```
{{ index .Doc.Users.Name 0}}
{{ index .Doc.Users 0 .Name}}
{{ .Name index .Quote.Clients 0}}
...
```

What is the correct syntax for just getting `.Name` field (`.Doc.Users[0].Name`) of the first element in my array?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Simply group the expression and apply the `.Name` selector:

```
<div>Foobar {{ (index .Doc.Users 0).Name }}</div>
```

Here's a runnable, verifiable example:

```
type User struct {
    Name  string
    Email string
}

t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(
    `<div>Foobar {{ (index .Doc.Users 0).Name }}</div>`))

m := map[string]interface{}{
    "Doc": map[string]interface{}{
        "Users": []User{
            {Name: "Bob", Email: "bob@myco.com"},
            {Name: "Alice", Email: "alice@myco.com"},
        },
    },
}

fmt.Println(t.Execute(os.Stdout, m))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wnDmxMBsYe_u)):

```
<div>Foobar Bob</div><nil>
```

*(The `<nil>` at the end is the error value returned by `template.Execute()`, telling there were no errors executing the template.)*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249941/discussion-between-nitin-nanivadekar-and-icza).