# First item in a template range

Tags: kubernetes, go-templates

how to run range for one time in go template

```
{{range  . }}
     <a href="/detailed/{{.Namespace}}">
     <p  style="text-align: center;font-size: 2rem;">{{.Namespace}}</p>
{{end}}
```

I need only first value of Namespace bY using this i am getting more than one values in html

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way

```
<a href="/detailed/{{ (index . 0).Namespace }}"><p  style="text-align: center;font-size: 2rem;">{{ (index . 0).Namespace }}</p>
```

Basically, what you want is to get the first element from the range which if you search hard it enough, you can find the answer in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52682621/how-to-access-value-of-first-index-of-array-in-go-templates).

Comment: If that's the case, would you mind marking this as the answer? Thanks :)