# cannot fetch a value from an interface in helm

Tags: go, syntax, syntax-error, kubernetes-helm

I am new to helm charts and have a problem in getting a key from a list. I am trying to parse the following structure:

`operation:map[initiatedBy:map[username:admin] retry:map[] sync:map[resources:[map[group:apps kind:Deployment name:dev-refresh-service namespace:dev-apps]]`

I am able to get the value of `username` inside the `initiatedBy` key using: `{{.operation.initiatedBy.username}}`

However I am not able to get the value for the `name` key from inside the list - `resources`

I am using the following syntax: `{{ operation.sync.resources.name }}`

Following is the error I get: `can't evaluate field name in type interface {}`

Any way around for this?? I am not really sure is this a helm issue or golang issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: try {{ operation.sync.resources[0].name }}

Comment: @taleodor Getting a new error:

```msg="Failed to parse new settings: template: app-sync-succeeded:1: bad character U+005B '['"```

Comment: Actually look at this SO - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52682621/how-to-access-value-of-first-index-of-array-in-go-templates - if you play around a bit, should get it done; essentially looks like the issue is that resources is an array in your case, so you need 1st element of that

Comment: @taleodor Will give it a try. Thank you :)

Comment: @taleodor It worked bro. Thanks a ton for this :)

Answer (score -1):

The most common reason I have found for this error in Helm is that there is no key in the `Values.yaml`

You are probably looking for something like (assuming that `operation.sync.resources.name` currently has no value)

```
operation:
  sync:
    resources:
      name: {}
```

Note: I have not filled out the entire structure of `operation:`
This can also happen if the values are for a sub-chart, in which case the top of that structure should begin with the chart name